how to stop user unit properly?
Starting a user unit
$ systemd-run --scope --user qemu-system-x86_64 -pidfile startedvm
Running as unit: run-r99922f9d145a4111bae22dd8aceb8515.scope; invocation ID: 10be8f45e7124b9e868f374023d4e06e

trying to stop the unit (everything shown is done as the same user id 1000) i get on the logs:


systemd[867]: run-r99922f9d145a4111bae22dd8aceb8515.scope: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.servi
ce/app.slice/run-r99922f9d145a4111bae22dd8aceb8515.scope, ignoring: Operation not permitted
systemd[867]: run-r99922f9d145a4111bae22dd8aceb8515.scope: Killing process 3743 (qemu-system-x86) with signal SIGKILL
systemd[867]: run-r99922f9d145a4111bae22dd8aceb8515.scope: Killing process 3746 (kvm-nx-lpage-recovery-3743) with signal SIGKILL


Same happens on system shutdown. The logs will show the unit (qemu) received only a SIGKILL. which causes it to not terminate properly. leaving things such as the pidfile around.
what is the correct way to start that user unit in a way it is properly terminated (e.g. SIGTERM, wait, then SIGKILL)
And why journal says "failed to kill control group" "Operation not permitted"? What is being attempted that would fail in this case?
